# how to give a placeholder in a textbox in wp7 application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am building an app for windows phone 7 where i have a textbox in which i want to place a placeholder.

My xaml is:

```
<TextBox Height="73" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,45,0,0"  Name="name"  Text="Name" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="419" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am getting your question right and also if my knowledge serves me correctly then

There is no special property for placeholders or water mark in wp7 textboxes

How ever you can customize a textbox to fit in accordance to your needs.

Its just very simple

Taking your textbox which is

```
<TextBox Height="73" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,45,0,0"  Name="name"  Text="Name" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="419" />
```

and subscribing to its GotFocusEvent

```
<TextBox GotFocus="OnGotFocus" Height="73" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,45,0,0"  Name="name"  Text="Name" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="419" />
```

do this in the event handler

```
private void OnGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (name.Text.Equals("Name", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        name.Text = string.Empty;
    }  
}
```

This could imitate your requirement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is working fine but there is a problem. The text that we assign like a placeholder is not taken as empty and the validation for the textbox doesnot work

Comment: Okay that is one special case, in that case you could use a watermark textbox control by codeplex, see the link http://watermarktextbox.codeplex.com/

Comment: Windows phone toolkit. PhoneTextBox control. Hint property.

Comment: The Telerik Rad Controls Textbox has a watermark also. That control alone is worth the telerik price tag

Answer (score 1):

You should try the PhoneTextBox from the Windows Phone Toolkit (http://phone.codeplex.com/) which has a Hint property

Answer (score 1):

You mean you have to place a cursor when App get's launched. If yes, then go for `GotFocus` event.

Try this :

```
<TextBox GotFocus="txt_OnGotFocus" Height="73" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,45,0,0"  Name="name"  Text="Name" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="419" />
```

**Code behind**

```
private void txt_OnGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if(this.name.Text == "Name")
   {
       this.name.Text = string.Empty;
   }
}
```